# Android Intent show error in new Uri

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

Code show an error when try declare a new Uri

follow code:

```
Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, new Uri("content://contacts"));
```

show an error

> "Cannot instantiate the type Uri"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of constructing a `Uri`, use the static `parse` method to create it:

```
Uri.parse("content://contacts");
```

Although, since you are accessing contacts, you should probably prefer using the static field `CONTENT_URI` from the `Contacts` class. See the SDK reference for [Contacts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html#CONTENT_URI).

This would make your code:

```
Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
```

Comment: `  E/AndroidRuntime(21477): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   E/AndroidRuntime(21477): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method pickContact(View) in the activity class com.example.enterpraise.Projeto for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'pick'
 E/AndroidRuntime(21477):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3686)
 E/AndroidRuntime(21477):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(21477): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: pickContact [class android.view.View]`

Comment: That crash doesn't have anything to do with the intent. It is telling you that you have no method named  `pickContact` which takes a `View` as a parameter. I assume you added the onClick attribute in your XML, and did not add the method to your Activity.

Comment: Without seeing exactly what you have, it's hard to tell. Either way, there is no way that creating an Intent as described above can cause that particular exception.

Comment: `static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 1;
 private void pickContact(View view) {
  Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
      pickContactIntent.setType(Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
      startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
    }`

Comment: and i put a method in xml `androidonClick:onClick="pickContact"`

Comment: I'm assuming this is a typo and you actually have: `android:onClick="pickContact"`. Anyway, try making your pickContact method public, and making sure that it is defined as a method of the Activity itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI ); 
pickContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE); 
startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
```